# How can I back to current frame in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm developing an automation test using Capybara and Ruby. I switch frame to access some WebElement in the Report page, and then I need to came back to current frame, but it doesn't have an ID. 
How can I do that?

This is my code when I switch frame to access the Report page:

```
def check_report(report)
  frame = @session.find("//*[@id=\"OF_jreport\"]")
  @session.switch_to_frame(frame)
end
```

Than I tried it:

```
 @session.switch_to.default_content()
```

I received a message asking if did I mean switch_to_frame, but it doesn't work too.

In my HTML code don't have another Iframe ID, and my WebElement xpath is `/html/body/div[11]/div[1]/div[2]/a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Capybara:**
I would suggest using `within_frame` so that the handle will set back once the operations are done in the frame.

```
def check_report(report)
  frame = @session.find("//*[@id=\"OF_jreport\"]")
  within_frame(frame) do
    # write your logic to perform operations in the frame
  end
end
```

Or you can try the below to switch to the default frame.

```
@session.switch_to_frame(:top)
```

**Ruby:**
Please use the below to switch to the default content.

```
 @session.switch_to_default_content
```

If you want to switch to the parent frame then use the below

```
@session.switch_to_parent_frame
```

Comment: I tried it and I received the follow message: undefined method `switch_to_default_content' for #<Capybara::Session>
      Did you mean?  switch_to_frame (NoMethodError)

Comment: sorry, I over looked the Capybara tag. You should be able to sue `:top` or `:parent` based on your requirement.

Comment: You can find more information [here](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb)